# in express.js what is the different between app.params() and router.params()?

Tags: node.js, express

in express.js 4, a Router is introduced to handle routes.

what is the diff between app.params() and router.params()? when to use each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params` is an object attached to the request containing the values of the tokens in the route, whereas `param` is a function:

`app.param()` is [this](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) -- it basically allows logic to be used for specific tokens defined in a route path.

`router.param()` is essentially the same thing as `app.param()` except the scope is different, it only applies to routes added to that router instance.